# React routing to get bundles in a subfolder

Tags: reactjs, iis, react-router

I've built a very simple React app, and I've installed under a subfolder, of an IIS10 website.

THe issue is that there is no way to tell react that it must take the static resources, js and css bundles chunks, under this folder and not directly on the root.

I've added both the homepage value in package.json and the basename in the BrowserRouter as described here: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter but it doesn't work.

This is the code in app.jsx:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import '@brains/ui/src/globals/scss/styles.scss';
import './fontawesome/all.css'
import './App.css';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter basename="/mySubFolder">
      <Switch>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/"
            render={(props) => <MyComponent {...props} />}
          />
      </Switch>    
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
export default App;
```

I've put the build on the server but the react app searches the static files always in [www.mydomain.com/static/..](http://www.mydomain.com/static/..). instead of [www.mydomain.com/mysubfolder/static/..](http://www.mydomain.com/mysubfolder/static/..).

What else can I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using create-react-app, all static files are normally served using the `PUBLIC_URL` environment variable. So you should be able to set it manually with either a `.env` file or using `EXPORT` (Or whichever is equivalent on your OS), so you get the following:

```
PUBLIC_URL=www.mydomain.com/mysubfolder/
```

This should make all static files served from `www.mydomain.com/mysubfolder/static/...` as you want. You can read more about it here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/

React-router has no influence on the static serving of files. It is *only* used for page routing.